# Understanding the following Push operation

Tags: java, push

I have some difficulties in understanding the following code. The part with the push operation and the stack is particularly obscure to me.

Could anyone please just give me an elaborated explanation on how it is working?

```
    package stack;        
    // Implement a "growable" stack.
    class DynStack implements IntStack {
        private int stck[];
        private int tos;
    // allocate and initialize stack
    DynStack(int size) {
        stck = new int[size];
        tos = -1;
    }
    // Push an item onto the stack
    public void push(int item) {
    // if stack is full, allocate a larger stack
    if(tos == stck.length-1) {
        int temp[] = new int[stck.length * 2]; // double size
        for(int i=0; i<stck.length; i++) temp[i] = stck[i];
            stck = temp;
            stck[++tos] = item;
        }
        else
            stck[++tos] = item;
        }
    // Pop an item from the stack
    public int pop() {
        if(tos < 0) {
            System.out.println("Stack underflow.");
            return 0;
        }
        else
            return stck[tos--];
        }
    }
    class IFTest2 {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            DynStack mystack1 = new DynStack(5);
            DynStack mystack2 = new DynStack(8);
            // these loops cause each stack to grow
            for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) mystack1.push(i);
            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) mystack2.push(i);
            System.out.println("Stack in mystack1:");
            for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
                System.out.println(mystack1.pop());
            System.out.println("Stack in mystack2:");
            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                System.out.println(mystack2.pop());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you try to re-establish the original indentation and formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple explanation:

`tos` is a pointer to the end of the stack. Push adds an element to the end of the stack. So first of all we check if we are pointing to the last element. If so, we can't add an element unless we resize the stack to hold more. So we create a new temp stack with double the size:

```
int temp[] = new int[stck.length * 2];
```

The next step is to put our items from the old stack to the new temporary stack and we do so by using this for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<stck.length; i++) temp[i] = stck[i];
```

After we've finished, we need to make this temporary stack the new stack:

```
stck = temp;
```

And then we add the item at the last position:

```
stck[++tos] = item;
```

Actually, this line and the else line can be removed.